# Markov time $ T= \min\{n : X[n] = 1\}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $T$ is a Markov time such that $T= \min \{ n : X[n] = 1\}$ , $X[n]$ is the number of $h$ (heads) in coin tossing for $n$ times. 
Let's say I will toss the coin 3 times, so the event collection is $\{hhh,hht,hth,htt,thh,tht,tth,ttt\}$.

Let $T\wedge n$ denote the minimum between $n$ and $T$ i.e., 
$$T\wedge n=\begin{cases} n & \mbox{ if }n< T,\\  T &\mbox{ if }n\geq T.\end{cases}$$

what is the value of $X[T\wedge 2] (tth)$?

the value of $X[T\wedge 2] (hhh) = 1$.

Please help since I am getting confused. I think $T$ is always $1$, which means

$$X[1\wedge 2] (tth) = X[1] (tth) = 0,$$

However when you look at it the following way :

$$X[(T\wedge 2)(tth)](tth) = X[3\wedge 2](tth)=X[2](tth)=0.$$

Although the answer is the same, but $X[1]$ is not the same as $X[2]$.

Comment: Why do you say that T is always 1?  This is not true. (By the way, I've changed the notation to make it clearer. Let me know if you don't understand my changes).

Comment: Your second method is correct, and the answer is 0.

Comment: I think T is always 1 because T= min {n:Xn =1 } , when I look at the set {n:Xn=1} , isn't this set is the collection of n (the times you toss the coin) which return Xn=1, for example at n=1,X1(h**) is always 1. At n=2 , X2(ttt)=0,X2(tth)=0 but X2(tht)=1. At n=3,X3(hhh)=3,X3(hth)=2,X3(tth)=1.So T equals min { 1,2,3} = 1 ,since each n gives a Xn =1.

Comment: No. The random variable $T$ picks out the time when the first $h$ occurs. So $T(hhh)=1$ is true, but $T(thh)=2$. The collection $\{n:X[n](\omega)=1\}$ is random, and depends on which $\omega$ you plug in. The set is not always $\{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\omega$ is some sample point, then the expression $X[T(\omega)\wedge 2](\omega)$ 
means that you should evaluate the time point $T(\omega)\wedge 2$ at $\omega$ and 
then substitute that time point into the $X$ process evaluated at the same $\omega$.

For example, if $\omega=tth$ then $T(\omega)=3$ so that $T(\omega)\wedge 2=3\wedge 2=2$.
Therefore $$X[T(tth)\wedge 2](tth) =X[2](tth)=0.$$ It is zero since no heads have been observed up to and including the second coin toss.

Comment: I appreciate your answer . However I got a little bit confuse. If w = tth, T(tth) is evaluated based on Xn(tth) right ? although Xn(tth)=1 at n =3 , but T is taken the minimum of 1,2,3. Why not T =1 ?

Comment: $X[1](tth)=0$, $X[2](tth)=0$, and $X[3](tth)=1$. So $\{n:X[n](tth)=1\}=\{3\}$. 
To define the set, you only include the time points $n$ with $X[n]=1$.

Comment: I think your point is that r.v T must be evaluated at each event w. However if that the case, why do they put the "min" in front of the {n:Xn=1}? When they put in the minimum , it makes me understanding that they want to find the minimum n in 3 times tossing that make Xn=1.

Comment: You are right, they want to find the minimum $n$ in 3 times tossing that make $X[n]=1$. This is what I have been saying all along. But don't forget to include the other variable: $X[n](\omega)=1$. The set of such $n$ depends on $\omega$.

Comment: It may be a useful exercise for you to calculate the set $A(\omega)=\{n: X[n](\omega)=1\}$ for all eight sample points $\omega\in\{ hhh,hht,hth,htt,thh,tht,tth,ttt\}.$

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. A(hhh)=A(hth)=A(hht)=A(htt)={1} . Then A(thh)=A(tht)={2};A(tth)={3};A(ttt)= null. In the comment above, if they want to find the minimum, is that the same meaning with the case without the "min" in front of the set ? i.e {n:Xn=1} only.Cuz what I see, the "min" is kind of irrelevant, when you hit a "h" in an event w , you know you get it already. However I can see "min" useful in case min {n:Xn>=1}.

Comment: $A(hth)=\{1,2\}$.

Comment: AH yessss !, I see, really appreciate you point out my mistake.That's true X[1](hth)=1,X[2](hth) also equals 1 as well, then X[3](hth)=2. Now I get why I made the mistake. I really appreciate your time to help me. I will have exam tomorrow though. My question for you in the previous post is non-sense since I do not understand at that time.

Comment: You're welcome. You didn't really need my help though. Just read the definitions *carefully*.